# Starting program hidden from VBS script no longer works

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

I've been using this VBS to start a batch script hidden for over 2 years now with no issues:

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Dev\broker\boot\boot.cmd" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Two days ago I started my PC and this just stopped working. It calls the batch script but also shows a command prompt window. I did not fiddle with the OS in any way and I did not update it either. I'm on Windows 10 1903 build 18362.53 installed on 21th of March (a month ago).

What could have changed and how do I make the above script work again?

Comment: If the console window is the `cmd` instance running the batch file it could be a bug. But by default it is `wscript.exe` who runs the `.vbs` file, maybe the default script engine has changed and you are seeing the console window associated to the  `cscript.exe`. Can you determine what script engine executable you are using?

Comment: Actually the CMD window is hidden, but inside the batch script it calls `php some-script.php` and what I see is actually the "php" console window (if that makes any sense). Why the `php` script starts as a new window rather than inside the current CMD is beyond me. Maybe I need to call it differently from within `boot.cmd` so it would also remain hidden?

Comment: We wouldn't know either, since you didn't provide any information about the batch script or the PHP installation/configuration.